# # of OpenCL devices on 2012 Macbook pro

Tags: macos, opencl, gpu, cpu, intel

I'm writing an openCL program on a mid 2012 13" macbook pro with the following specs:

Processor: 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000

In my program I do the following to check how many devices I have access to:

```
// get first platform
cl_platform_id platform;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

// get device count
cl_uint gpuCount;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &gpuCount);

cl_uint cpuCount;
err |= clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, NULL, &cpuCount);

std::cout<<"NUM CPUS: "<<cpuCount<<" NUM GPUS: "<<gpuCount<<std::endl;
```

After execution, my program states that I have only ***one CPU*** and ***zero GPUs***.

How can that be? Is openCL not compatible with Intel HD Graphics 4000 card? And I thought my computer had a dual core processor. So shouldn't there be 2 CPUs and 1 GPU?

Or am I simply not fetching the data correctly?

**EDIT**: I have found the issue. After upgrading my OS to Mavericks (was previously running Mountain Lion), openCL now recognizes my graphics card as a valid device.

Comment: You can verify your results with GPU caps viewer app. Can be found at http://www.geeks3d.com/20140312/gpu-caps-viewer-1-20-1-released/

Comment: According to [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5942) your machine should run OpenCL 1.2. What comes to the CPU, even it is dual core it is still one compute unit. So 1 CPU is correct. Otherwise you would see hundreds of GPUs every time there is one installed.

Comment: @bl0z0 so why is it that it still says 0 GPUs?

Comment: With compute unit I mean OpenCL device. I don't know anything about Macs, if it was a linux or windows I would say that your driver is not properly working.

Comment: Maybe you need to install cl drivers for Intel manually

Comment: Does anyone else have the same computer I do that can weigh in?

Comment: Which version of OS X and XCode have you got?

Answer (score 4):

Your processor has multiple cores, which are recognized as Compute Units. Run following code snippet & check that number of CU is as expected:

```
cl_device_id device;
cl_uint max_compute_units;
cl_int ret = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(cl_uint), &max_compute_units, NULL);
printf("Number of computing units: %u\n", max_compute_units);
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question, (and doesn't need downvoting please) but hopefully will help you work out what you have actually got installed. I would have posted it as a comment, but the formatting there would be useless.

If you want a legible list of your installed CPU and Graphics equipment, the following command does it nicely:

```
system_profiler | awk '/^Hardware/ || /^Graphics/{p=1;print;next} /^[A-Za-z]/{p=0} p'

Graphics/Displays:

    AMD Radeon HD 6970M:

      Chipset Model: AMD Radeon HD 6970M
      Type: GPU
      Bus: PCIe
      PCIe Lane Width: x16
      VRAM (Total): 1024 MB
      Vendor: ATI (0x1002)
      Device ID: 0x6720
      Revision ID: 0x0000
      ROM Revision: 113-C2960H-203
      EFI Driver Version: 01.00.560
      Displays:
        iMac:
          Display Type: LCD
          Resolution: 2560 x 1440
          Pixel Depth: 32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
          Main Display: Yes
          Mirror: Off
          Online: Yes
          Built-In: Yes

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: iMac
      Model Identifier: iMac12,2
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 3.4 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 8 MB
      Memory: 16 GB
      Boot ROM Version: IM121.0047.B1F
      SMC Version (system): 1.72f2
      Serial Number (system): DGKH90PWDHJW
      Hardware UUID: 1025AC04-9F8E-5342-9EF4-XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And also this for the actual CPU details:

```
sysctl -a | grep "brand_string"
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

And this for OpenCL version:

```
system_profiler | grep -A 11 OpenCL:
OpenCL:

  Version: 2.3.59
  Obtained from: Apple
  Last Modified: 19/09/2014 10:28
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
  Signed by: Software Signing, Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Get Info String: 2.3.59, Copyright 2008-2013 Apple Inc.
  Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework
  Private: No
```

P.S. If there is a better way to provide additonal, useful information (which is not really a proper answer) on SO than this, please let me know.